# Optmize download data from database using java

Tags: java, sql-server, database, oracle11g, oracle10g

We are downloading around 10 million data from oracle/mssql database using java.

We are fetching 5000 records at a time and fetching 5000 records takes 5 minutes depending on where condition,so fetching and downloading 10 milion records will take (10million/5000) *5 minutes i.e. 10000 minutes.

We have tried fetching 100000 records at a time,but it might run into heap space issue.

Is there any way to optimize that?

Comment: Setting `fetchSize` to large values will not help but will consume much more memory. Try with `fetchSize = 100`. How much time does it take to fetch all data in database? Maybe the issue is not in Java/JDBC but in SQL query itself? If query is fast maybe you can split it somehow to fetch data into several Java threads

Comment: The problem here is we are executing same query again and again after every 5000 records changing rownum from 1-5000 and 5000-10000 and soon till 10 million,that query is taking 5 minutes even in database,is there any way to execute query only once and fetch all records from that in the group of 5000.

Comment: With oracle driver for JDBC you execute query once and then just iterate over `ResultSet`. Driver loads data by batches of `fetchSize` records into memory.

Comment: The thing is if we execute query once,then all the 10 million data is loaded in result set,which will cause heap memory,thats why we are fetching 5k rows at a time.

Comment: Depending on what you use to execute query but with plain old JDBC and oracle SQL driver only `fetchSize` is loaded into memory. Of course if you not add every record into one huge `List` or any other collection

Comment: i am using ibatis and storing result as a list

Comment: Then you can at least start several of those queries in parallel in several threads

Answer (score 0):

You will need to determine the number of records you can safely return the query. You will need to take a look at how big is the size of a record on average, RecordSize and you will need to determine MaxSize. The number of records you can load this way is

MaxSize / RecordSize

But you might want to load less records, to avoid issues from records being slightly larger in average than expected:

0.9 * MaxSize / RecordSize

Also, you will need to optimize your query to:

- not load unnecessary columns
- make where, having and on clauses quicker

And you could separate your query into a two-step approach: first you run the query with the real conditions and get only the ids, then query the real columns using only the ids as condition. This is especially helpful if you happen to use joins to gather some of the columns and you do not need all the joins when you gather the ids.

Also, you can improve your database by normalizing it if it is not normalized and indexing the columns you are performing your conditions on. However, you need to be careful with the indexing, because although it speeds up reads, it slows down the writes.